# A-Frame library limits on mobile?

Tags: ios, aframe

This plunker shows a simple **VR scene with the A-Frame** library (a plane + ~10 lights).

It runs great on desktop whichever the quantity of lights.

The mobile iOS version loads at 60fps with 11 lights but **shows a blank page with 12+ lights**.

The stats show perfectly, I used WeInRe to output the console with no particular warning.

Is there a limitation of the complexity of the scene?

Thanks.

Regards,
JD

---

- A-Frame Version: 0.4.0
- Platform / Device:  iOS 10.2 / iPhone 6s -  Chrome & Safari
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:

  Editable : 
  `https://plnkr.co/edit/Am8rjMdeaPzUWnFKX2i1?p=preview`

  Fullscreen preview : 
  `https://run.plnkr.co/CgcUZgDUuPfeY15R/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lights are expensive. I believe three.js has a limit on the number of lights, and there might be hardware constraints. It may be 60fps with just one plane, but each object you add will have to factor in 12 lights, the scene will quickly degrade.

Check out deferred renderer for many lights. Not sure if it works on mobile. https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-deferred-renderer

Comment: Thank you for your support. I thought I could leverage the "distance" param of a-light, but with little success. However, I manage to restore great mobile performance : I swiched off the farthest lights with visible="false", depending on user position. I have tested deferred renderer but not enough to develop on it. Solved for me.